# How Do I remove Duplicate from 1 column via formula in libreoffice

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, libreoffice

I have some data created by libreoffice macro but some articles are duplicate in one column with different prices so I can't use those data

Here is an example :

9876543210 - 1.10
1234567890 - 2.3
8523697410 - 6.0
9876543210 - 8.6
7878754587 - 9.6
1234567890 - 66.6

Now see record 1 and 4 both numbers are same but price are different I simply want to delete whole 4th raw
Same as data number 2nd and 6th are same with different price and I want to remove 6th raw

If any formula are available then I could write macro code using record macro
like =CounfIf(....)

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the criteria for removal? Always the second entry? Lowest price?

Answer (score 0):

If the duplicate rows were exactly the same, then a filter would work.  But since they are not, follow the procedure here:

https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Removing_Duplicate_Rows

Comment: Hey Jim I dont want o compare whole row, I only need to compare only one column ; Simple If One entry is more then 1 time then keep first entry only and rest can be removed :)